# Residue of $ctg(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Find the residue of $$ctg(z)$$

$cos(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{z^{2n}}{2n!}$

$sin(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$

So $ctg(z)=\frac{cos(z)}{sin(z)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{2n}\frac{2n+1}{z}$

And the poles are at $n\pi$ how can I find $Res(f,\pi n)?$

Comment: That's not the [Laurent series for cotangent](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Laurent_Series_Expansion_for_Cotangent_Function).  You seem to be using $$\frac{a+b}{c+d}=\frac{a}{c}=\frac{b}{d},$$ and you know that's not right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really believe that $\cot$ is a constant function?

Anyway$$(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):\operatorname{Res}(\cot z,n\pi)=\frac{\cos(n\pi)}{\sin'(n\pi)}=1.$$

Comment: Correct, so I got it wrong in $\frac{z^{2n}}{z^{2n+1}}=\frac{1}{z}$, which limit did you take to find the residue?

Comment: $$\operatorname{Res}\bigl(f(z),a\bigr)=\lim_{z\to a}(z-a)f(z).$$

Comment: So we got $lim_{z\to n\pi }\frac{(z-n\pi)(\cos z)}{\sin z}$

Comment: If you meant$$\lim_{z\to n\pi}(z-n\pi)\frac{\cos z}{\sin z},$$then, yes.

Comment: I do not see how you got to this limit, so the limit is $0$? why did you get to $sin'(n \pi)?$

Comment: If $f(z)=\frac{a_{-1}}{z-a}+a_0+a_1(z-a)+a_2(z-a)^2+\cdots,$ then\begin{align}\operatorname{Res}\bigl(f(z),a\bigr)&=a_{-1}\\&=\lim_{z\to a}a_{-1}+a_0(z-a)+a_1(z-a)^2+\cdots\\&=\lim_{z\to a}(z-a)f(z).\end{align}

Comment: I understand why you used this limit, I do not understand why it is equal to $\frac{\cos(n\pi)}{\sin'(n\pi)}$

Comment: \begin{align}\lim_{z\to n\pi}(z-n\pi)\frac{\cos z}{\sin z}&=\lim_{z\to n\pi}\frac{\cos z}{\frac{\sin(z-n\pi)}{z-n\pi}}\\&=\frac{\cos(n\pi)}{\sin'(n\pi)}.\end{align}

Comment: @newhere Is it clear now?

Comment: Clear like the sun, Thanks